# O que ha de errado neste codigo Python?

Tags: python, pycharm

Fala ae galera, entao, estou aprendendo python pelo curso em video e estou na aula 9, Ex23, e eu estou tentando (por uma forma matematica) mostrar os numeros divididos para a pessoa, so que ele da erro, e eu nao tenho a menos ideia do que fazer aqui, e mesmo com o Pycharm me dizendo que a algo de errado, eu n entendo o que a de errado:

```
Nam = input(int('Qual o numero (de 1 ate 9999)?'))
M = (Nam//1000)
C = Nam-(M*1000)
C = C//100
D = Nam-((M*1000)+(C*100))
D = D//10
lol = Nam-((M*1000)+(C*100)+(D*10))
print(M)
print(C)
print(D)
print(lol)
```

o Pycharm fica me dizendo que o "Nam" tem algo de errado, mas eu nao sei o que é

Comment: Não seria: `Nam = int(input('Qual o numero (de 1 ate 9999)?'))`, lê uma string e converte o que foi lido para int?

Comment: `int('texto')` tenta converter o texto para número, e como o texto "Qual é o número etc" não é um número, dá erro. O certo é primeiro obter o texto do `input` e depois tentar converter para número (ou seja, `int(input(texto))`, como já foi dito acima)

Answer (score 2):

Basta trocar o int com o input de lugar.
Seu código no momento está assim:

```
Nam = input(int('Qual o numero (de 1 ate 9999)?'))
```

O correto seria definir o tipo de variável **(str, flot, int, bool)** antes do input:

```
Nam = int(input('Qual o numero (de 1 ate 9999)?'))
```